# Classloading issue with OSGi and JNI

Tags: hibernate, java-native-interface, log4j, classloader, apache-felix

I have an OSGi application which starts and runs fine from command line. In production environment, however, this application has to be started from small program written in C. This program checks license, does other stuff and starts java virtual machine using JNI with my application. In this way, I got strange errors from log4j and hibernate (I've enabled the -verbose:class JVM flag):

```
[Loaded org.apache.log4j.Appender from reference:file:/opt/dc/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.log4j.Appender from file:/opt/dc/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar]
...
[Loaded org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender from file:/opt/dc/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar]
log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" object is not assignable to a     "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
log4j:ERROR [org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl@eafb71] whereas object of type 
log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" was loaded by [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1cde100].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "ROLLINGFILE".
...
[Loaded org.dom4j.DocumentFactory from reference:file:/opt/dc/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar]
...
[Loaded org.dom4j.DocumentFactory from file:/opt/dc/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar]
...
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to     org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.getInstance(DocumentFactory.java:97)
    at org.dom4j.io.DOMReader.<init>(DOMReader.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper.createDOMReader(XMLHelper.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1615)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1218)
```

Why are those classes loaded twice? Why are some of them loaded from Felix and some from Java classloader? I have a suspicion that some native code calls java (for example logging) before the OSGi application is started and than those loaded classes are somehow reused causing ClassCastExceptions - how can I prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside the program launcher. It was adding all the bundles to the classpath for the JVM although only the Felix jar was necessary.